# What happened to science.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, area-51, stack-exchange

I was interested in a certain question over there - now the site is gone and I can't find any information about it.

Side question: what is stackexchange-2.0 compared to stackexchange ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Exchange 1.0 was the model that allowed people to pay for having their own Stack Exchange site. This model has been discontinued and isn't available anymore.

Stack Exchange 2.0 is the model in which creating new sites does not cost money anymore; instead, sites are created through a democratic process on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com). See the [blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/) for more details.

science.stackexchange.com was a Stack Exchange 1.0 site.

Comment: so, is science.SE gone or will a dump be made available?

Comment: @Tobias The SE 1.0 data is privately owned, so I think you'll have to ask those people.

Answer (score 5):

The science.stackexchange.com site was a privately-owned site back when folks built their own Stack Exchange sites that we hosted as a subscription service.

Their site expired several months ago and I do not know if the owner chose to export or publish their data, or if they have plans to continue the site.

Answer (score 4):

If you know some of the content of that question it may still be possible to recover the question by using the Google cache.

For instance, I just recovered one of my questions by searching Google as

```
site:science.stackexchange.com liquid nitrogen
```

and saving the content of the link "Cached" for the search hit "What is the pressure of contained nitrogen at room temperature ..." to disk.

Act now! Or else it will soon be too late.

Comment: http://www.archive.org/web/web.php Could tell you eventually, probably.